# Laravel login error "These credentials do not match our records."

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, login

Al intentar hacer login, me devuelve este error

> These credentials do not match our records.

EDIT: Al añadir este código a `User.php`, ya no me devuelve ningún error, pero no me loguea:

```
public function getAuthPassword()
{
    return $this->PASSWORD;
}
```

El registro me funciona correctamente, y, después del registro, hace el login automático, pero después ya no inicia sesión.

Este es mi modelo `User.php`:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'ID', 'EMAIL', 'PASSWORD', 'ROL', 'DEPARTAMENTO'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'PASSWORD'
    ];

    /**
     * The table associated with the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'T_USUARIOS';

    /**
     * Indicates if the model should be timestamped.
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    public $timestamps = false;

}
```

El `LoginController.php`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    /**
     * Get the login username to be used by the controller.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function username()
    {
        return 'EMAIL';
    }

    /**
     * Validate the user login request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return void
     *
     * @throws \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException
     */
    protected function validateLogin(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            $this->username() => 'required|string',
            'PASSWORD' => 'required|string',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Get the needed authorization credentials from the request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    protected function credentials(Request $request)
    {
        return $request->only($this->username(), 'PASSWORD');
    }
}
```

Por si sirve de algo, dejo también el `RegisterController.php`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
    */

    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'EMAIL' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:T_USUARIOS'],
            'PASSWORD' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'EMAIL' => $data['EMAIL'],
            'PASSWORD' => Hash::make($data['PASSWORD']),
            'ROL' => 'admin',
            'DEPARTAMENTO' => 'sistemas'
        ]);
    }
}
```

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Posiblemente porque tengas indicarle al modelo qué campo deseas usar como contraseña. Por defecto sería el campo de la `password`, y no `PASSWORD`. Prueba sobreescribir el método `getAuthPassword()` en el modelo User para que retorne `$this->PASSWORD`

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ Gracias! Ahora esto no me devuelve ningún tipo de error pero no loguea al usuario

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con "no loguea al usuario" y en qué parte del código tienes la lógica para hacer el login del usuario? https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authentication#authenticating-users